# Drag & drop - getData() returns empty string

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a simple web app that could read and display a plain text file. I want it to open the files just by dragging and dropping them on a `div`.

This is my code that handles the drop event:

```
dropHere.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  console.log(data);
});
```

Pretty straightforward, huh? Only... it logs an empty `string`.
I'm really confused. Am I missing some trivial thing?

`e.dataTransfer.files[0]` returns a `File` object, with the correct filename, size, and even file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I went through a few pages that allow drag & drop file uploading and found a solution to this problem. Use `FileReader` instead of `getData()`.

This is how the code looks now (generated from CoffeeScript):

```
var loadFile;

empty.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
  var file, files, i, len, results;
  e.preventDefault();
  files = e.dataTransfer.files;
  results = [];
  for (i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
    file = files[i];
    results.push(loadFile(file));
  }
  return results;
});

loadFile = function(file) {
  var reader;
  reader = new window.FileReader;
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    return content.innerHTML = reader.result;
  };
  return reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

Everything works fine now.